# Testing renderer.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d') in Angular jest

Tags: javascript, angular, jestjs, ts-jest, typescript2.0

I have following typescript code:

```
getWidth(value: string): number {
        const text = this.renderer.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
        const { font } = getComputedStyle(
            this.el.nativeElement
        );

        text.font = font;

        return text.measureText(value).width;
    }
```

And I am trying to test it in Angular Jest.

I have added the following in beforeEach()

```
beforeEach(() => {
        HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = jest.fn();
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });
```

Whenever I try to run it, I get 'Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'font')' How can I define text?

Comment: are you sure you've set `text` correctly?  What does `getContext('2d')` return here?  Wouldn't you want to set `text = this.renderer.createElement('canvas');` and then in another call you set (not get?) the context as 2d?

Comment: The getContext() method returns a drawing context on the canvas. The code is working fine. I have to test it.

Comment: Oh... wow I'm sorry I assumed both methods were in your test. Now I see what you mean! So what does `jest.fn()` return here?  I assume that's what will replace the default `getContext()` method for testing?  Can you just mock the object that you expect there? `HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = (ctx:string)=>({text:{font:''}});`

Comment: Type '(ctx: string) => { text: { font: string; }; }' is not assignable to type '{ (contextId: "2d", options?: CanvasRenderingContext2DSettings): CanvasRenderingContext2D; (contextId: "bitmaprenderer", options?: ImageBitmapRenderingContextSettings): ImageBitmapRenderingContext; (contextId: "webgl", options?: WebGLContextAttributes): WebGLRenderingContext; (contextId: "webgl2", options?: WebGLCon...'.
  Type '{ text: { font: string; }; }' is missing the following properties from type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': canvas, getContextAttributes, globalAlpha, globalCompositeOperation, and 61 more.

Comment: you could force it with a `//@ts-ignore` comment just for testing purposes. No guarantees, this is purely a guess by me!

Comment: Doesn't seem to help

Comment: use `jsdom` or at least `canvas`

Comment: @TachibanaShin Can you show jsdom example?

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-jquery